# Make multiple pages out of a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

So, i have this database right, with some fields called 'id', 'title' and 'message'. Now i got like 700 messages in the database. So all i wanna do, is set a limit of max 50 message title's per page, and make multiple pages... How can i do that?

I only know to get the first page, using `LIMIT`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you guessed, you have to use the [**`LIMIT`** keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html#id847922).

It accepts two value *(quoting)* :

- the offset of the first row to return
- the maximum number of rows to return

In your case, you'll have to use something like this for the first page :

```
select * from your_table order by ... limit 0, 50
```

And, then, for the second page :

```
select * from your_table order by ... limit 50, 50
```

And for the third one :

```
select * from your_table order by ... limit 100, 50
```

And so on ;-)

**Edit after the comment :** to get the page number, you'll have to receive it from your URLs, that would look like this :

```
http://www.example.com/page.php?pagenum=2
```

Then, you'll calculate the first value for the limit, :

```
$offset = 50 * intval($_GET['pagenum']);
```

And inject it in your query :

```
select * from your_table order by ... limit $offset, 50
```

Constructing URLs to the differents pages is now a matter of getting URLs such as these :

```
http://www.example.com/page.php?pagenum=0
http://www.example.com/page.php?pagenum=1
http://www.example.com/page.php?pagenum=2
...
```

If you know you have 700 elements, and 50 per page, you'll have 700/50 pages ;-)

So, something like this should do the trick :

```
for ($i=0 ; $i<700/50 ; i++) {
    // Use http://www.example.com/page.php?pagenum=$i as URL
}
```

Of course, 700 is a value that can probably change, and should not be hard-coded : it should be determined from the database, using a `count` query :

```
select count(*) as total
from your_table
...
```

Comment: Ah, great! But how can i add a menu to that? That i only get links for pages 1 / 14?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP file may receive a GET argument being the page number.

Then you do your query with LIMIT ($page_number * $messages_per_page), $messages_per_page (pseudo-code).

$messages_per_page = 50 in your case. $page_number is deduced from a GET argument, *after sanitizing*, the first page being page number 0.