# Fill empty cells in table

Tags: php, html, mysql

Basically I have a ranking-page that I'm working on for my CS:GO server. So far it's working fine, and it's looking like this:

https://puu.sh/aJlTj/b6fb5a7a06.png

[image]

And the next-page arrow(s) works fine, but the problem is, at page 3+, it's empty because there haven't been more players on the server yet, and it looks like this:

https://puu.sh/aJlXH/7e69071a2b.png

[image]

I am using the answer from [Make multiple pages out of a mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127918/make-multiple-pages-out-of-a-mysql-query) in order to create the pages for all the players.

My table-printing-part looks like this:

```
echo "<div class='TableGen'><table border='1'><tr><td>Name</td><td>Wins</td><td>Losses</td><td>ELO</td></tr>";
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM multi1v1_stats ORDER BY wins DESC LIMIT $offset,15");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['wins'] . "</td><td>" . $row['losses'] . "</td><td>" . $row['rating'] . "</td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

`$offset` is declared by using `$offset = 15 * intval($_GET['page']);` unless it's the first page, then it's set to 0.

I understand that this code will only echo out `<tr><td></td></tr>`'s as long as there's data to post, so how would I go about checking if the page's cells are empty, then just echo out empty cells? (due to this, I can't use `empty-cells: show;` either as there are no cells to show, not even empty ones)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe add a counter with your query while loop and have a loop at the end to add the extra ones. Also you might want to have a page limit where you count the rows that get outputted and divide by numberperpage to get number of pages.

Comment: @Class I was actually thinking about something like that (the get total amount of rows, then divide) but wanted to see if there were any other ideas on how I could do this. :) Thanks for the answer, +1.

Comment: Looks like you have specified a height to your table instead of leaving it automatic.

Comment: Why have a "Next" button at all if there aren't going to be any results on the next page anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want...  It basically finds the number of rows that were returned and then continues with blanks until the limit is reached.

```
$limit = 15;
echo "<div class='TableGen'><table border='1'><tr><td>Name</td><td>Wins</td><td>Losses</td><td>ELO</td></tr>";
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM multi1v1_stats ORDER BY wins DESC LIMIT $offset,$limit");
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $i = $i+1;
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['wins'] . "</td><td>" . $row['losses'] . "</td><td>" . $row['rating'] . "</td></tr>";
}
for($i=$i;$i<=$limit;$i++)[
    echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
 }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: PS:  This isn't tested :)